# Python: Changing Types while writing in a MS-Access DB

Tags: python, ms-access

I' m trying to read data from a DB (MS-Access), manipulate them and then write them back after creating a new table. 
Basically everything work well (read, write, create table), but the Problem I'm facing is as follows:

First the table I created has 5 fields with the following types:

```
Types = ['integer', 'varchar(12)', 'integer', 'double', 'date']
```

The Data I wanna write is of the form:

```
Items = ['1', 'Widgit', '5.0', '15.1234', '2009-01-29 13:05:30']
```

As you can see the data-elements have the type `str`. So Normally I should do something like:

```
[Type(Item) for (Type, Item) in zip(Types, Items)]
```

But that is not going to work since my types are not **pythonic**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to do the conversion in python or VBA?

Comment: I'm working with python using adodbapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps use a little function to map "database" types to "Python" types, maybe something like this?

```
def get_py_type(access_type):
    if access_type == "integer":
        return "int"
    elif access_type.startswith("varchar"):
        return "str"
    elif access_type == "double":
        return "float"
    elif access_type == "date":
        return "datetime"
    else:
        return "unknown"
```

so then you could map your existing list to the list of Python types

```
>>> Types = ['integer', 'varchar(12)', 'integer', 'double', 'date']
>>> pyTypes = [get_py_type(item) for item in Types]
>>> print pyTypes
['int', 'str', 'int', 'float', 'datetime']
>>>
```

and then carry on from there?

Answer (score 0):

You may create another `list` for conversion with the equivalent Python types and use it as:

```
Conversion_list = [int, str, int, float, str]
# Python float is ~double, else use Decimal;
```

> In the SQL query date might be parsed as string

Then you may create a new list as:

```
[Conversion(Item) for (Conversion, Item) in zip(Conversion_list, Items)]
```

---

If date is not parsed as `str`, you may create a `list` without date and at the end append date in the list item. For that you may use `strptime` from the `datetime` module.

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.